# How to delete file content in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Is possible to delete only file content in Google Drive? i.e I wanted to delete content stream of a particulate file, not the file.

If possible, can some one explain the process?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you added the realtime API tag, do you mean how do you delete the realtime data associated with a Drive file? If so, then maybe rephrase the question a bit and I'll answer it (if not, however, you can upload empty content using that example you provided... also answerable).

Answer (score 1):

You can sync. the Google Drive using a local folder and edit it locally.
Syncing locally depends on your OS - download the application from https://www.google.com/drive/download/. After you'll have it locally and the folder is synced, you can update the file (in your case, open the file and delete its content) and it will be empty on the next sync.

Comment: Sorry Yorammi, I am not clear with my question.

Actually my question is, how to delete byte stream of a google drive file using REST api?

Comment: This aproach is not not working in Google Drive v3 rest api.